# Why does 0.5 minus 0.4 equal 0.09999999999999998 instead of 0.01?

Tags: javascript

When you ask javascript to minus decimals, a lot of them (like 0.5-0.4) will not give you the correct answer. For example 0.5-0.4 should equal 0.1 but instead gives 0.09999999999999998.

```
console.log(0.5-0.4);
0.09999999999999998
```

I tried to search but couldn't find an answer. Is there an easy solution to this without doing a workaround like taking out the decimal and then putting it back in?